# How to get IP address via java or javascript?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery

My computer name is `D*******`.
When it is not connected to VPN client it gives same ip address from ipconfig and `www.jsonip.com` too.

But when I connect to VPN client the ip4 address changes to ppp adapter ip address, whereas the `www.jsonip.com` site still retrieves Ethernet ip4 address.

Is there a javascript or java way to get ip address via resolving the Computer Name?

Comment: Are you sure all Internet traffic is routed through the VPN? What do other IP lookup sites say?

Comment: @Thilo Yes, but sometimes when I disconnect it my API does not work.
I am trying to find a solution for this. `url: 'http://'+domainName+':9001/jolokia/read/*',`

Comment: @Thilo The domain name needs to be dynamics. So I need a dns resolver which resolves the IP address on the basis of my computer name.

Comment: java and javascript in the same question? this is a circus, brother.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, but if I get an answer in java then I need to use Spring MVC to convert it to json which can be accessed from a url, if in javascript then well and good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**JAVA** check this..

```
import java.net.InetAddress;

public class GetIPAddress {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            InetAddress thisIp = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            System.out.println("IP:" + thisIp.getHostAddress());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Another **JAVA** sample Code

```
 InetAddress Address = InetAddress.getLocalHost(); 
 System.out.println(Address); 
 Address = InetAddress.getByName("google.com"); 
 System.out.println(Address);
```

For **JS** Try this javaScript code it might help you.

[Superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/462977/can-javascript-be-used-to-extract-ones-ip-if-theyre-using-a-vpn)

[http://jsfiddle.net/](http://jsfiddle.net/ParthAkbari/9ZrLz/81/)

Comment: Its working fine when I do this: `InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("D*******");`

But not the one you did. Any idea why?

Comment: Yup, I know that it works, any idea how to do the same in JavaScript.

Comment: That does not work . It does not change when I connect to my vpn client.

Comment: Ok leave that. 
I have found a way I need a way to convert this to json and deploy it on a server so that I can access it via ajax url. Any suggestions on that.

Comment: I used spring MVC to convert it to JSON format and deploy it in a server.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
import java.net.InetAddress;

class IPAddress
{
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
 {
   System.out.println(InetAddress.getLocalHost());
 }
}
```

Comment: Nope not working. The output does not change when I connect to vpn client